# Advantages of using log4j or logback in applet

Tags: java, applet

It's justified to use this loggers in applet? They size is > 300kb, it's not so few for applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not justified. Not only size is the problem.

Your applet should be signed with a valid certificate (or local security policy altered for each user who use this applet) to let the log4j/logback opening files (or sockets) on the client workstation.

If you have the applet signed, then is no use to have the logs on the client workstation. Use Log4j/Logback only for development.

Comment: yes, my applet is signed. I worry about size of this logger dependencies. So it's better to use `System.out` instead `log4j` or `Logback`?

Comment: I don't want  log to files on client's machine, or open some sockets to log to server

Comment: For development you can use logback or log4j, but for release just write to system out only the exceptions.